# Submit form not works in Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom-events

I am having an issue with the form submission in mobile devices. Used a form and set the `method="post"`, and on submission calling a function`onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();`. 
I am not using Jquery or Jquery Mobile, Is it possible to set form action using javascript in mobile?
Even I am not able to alert the values in mobile while I am getting everything alerted in Desktop.

**Purpose:**

When submit the form it will redirect to another page and displays the search result there.

**Result:**

It's working fine with desktop browsers, but when I am trying to browse using mobile browser it's not working.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSubmitForm() {
        alert('Searching');
        //document.search_form.action = "/SearchConvention.aspx?SearchString=" + document.getElementById("search_term").value;
        document.search_form.action = "/SearchResults.aspx?terms=" + document.getElementById("search_term").value;
var staticStr = "/SearchResults.aspx?terms=";
    alert(staticStr);
    var searcTxt = $('#search_term').val();
    alert(searcTxt);
    var urlSet = staticStr + searcTxt;
    alert(urlSet);
        return true;
    }
  </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form" >
    <div class="input-group">
        <form id="search_form" name="search_form" method="post" class="searchform" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">
            <input id="search_term" name="search_term" type="text" value="" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <button type="submit" value="go"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By default jQuery-mobile submit form with ajax, so you should use  **data-ajax="false"** in the form.

Comment: @mizanurahma Thanks, I tried that still nothing changed in mobile device.

Comment: @mizanurahma Do I need to add Jquery Mobile in the website to work this feature?

Comment: Can anybody help me to solve this out?

Comment: do you have any public url to try with ? It could  be due to Mobile browser itself

Comment: @codebased I tried it with both mobile browser and Google chrome emulation in the desktop. Let me check about the public url or fiddle

Comment: fiddle will be good and will emulate here..

Comment: @codebased please find the fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/mshafeequemsn/8f4dnhd5/ but it's not working in the fiddle, I will update and let you know

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function formSubmit() {

var searchCriteria = document.getElementById("search_term").value;

if ( searchCriteria.length == 0 )
{
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.returnValue = false; // for IE as dont support preventDefault;
     }

     return;
} 
    document.search_form.action = "/SearchResults.aspx?terms=" + searchCriteria;
    document.search_form.submit();
}

    </script>

    <div class="form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <form id="search_form" name="search_form" method="post" class="searchform"  >
            <input id="search_term" name="search_term" type="text" value="" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <button type="button" value="go" id="SearchSubmit" onclick="formSubmit()">Go!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately it didn't worked in the mobile device as earlier. I don't know what's wrong with that.

Comment: but didn't worked for me. May be some mark up issue. I tried to add an alert and it worked, but the res of the thing not happening.
I will check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

You should to add jQuery or change definition of urlSet variable to document.getElementById('search_term').value;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some responsive API e.g. Bootstrap, just make sure
you set the proper col-md- col-xs- width values
The same happened with me, and I noticed in browser developer mode Elements tab that one of the
form-group div was covering the area of the submit button only when I descreased the 
width of the browser or viewd the page on mobile.